# object flips while snapping to another object with align rotation, using face snapping

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms, snapping

I try to snap the object that is selected in the screenshot onto the object behind it, similar to the one seen on the left edge on the screenshot (from which I copied the selected object). I want it to 'align rotation', so that is selected.

[image: object to snap with 'snap during transform' options]

I then press <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to maintain the height. However, when i hover over the surface I want to snap it to, it flips it's rotation, seemingly by 90 degrees:

[image: weird rotation flipping]

I applied rotation to both objects beforehand. Any clues? Thanks in advance.

I use Blender 2.74.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you applied the rotation, then this is working as expected. Transform snapping will align the transformed object's local Z axis to the normal of the face to which the object is snapped.

To visualize where the object's local axes are, set the [*Transform orientation*](http://blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/transform_orientations.html) to *Local* in *3D view > Header*:

[image]

Since your object's local Z is aligned to the world Z, this means that the local Z is aligned with one of the small sides of the object:

[image]
<sup>Note the direction of the blue arrow, which is indicating the object's local Z axis.</sup>

If you use an object with a local Z axis pointing out of the large side, then it works as desired:

[image]

To rotate the object's coordinates without changing the geometry, see [Is there a way to rotate the origin without rotating the geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8892/599) and [Set rotation values without applying them](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10877/599).

Answer (score 1):

This will work on rotated objects in my addon, [Mesh Align Plus](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/Mesh_Align_Plus) (make sure there's no non-uniform scaling, though):

[image]