# Snapping faces: wrong orientation

Tags: faces, snapping

I'm a new Blender user. I have a shape which is a cube section (I made it with the boolean modifier and two planes). Then, I set its origin on the center of one face, which I want to "glue" to another plane. I tried to use the snap tool, with the settings "**face**" and "**center**", checking the "**align rotation to target**" option.

As you can see on my screen, the mesh does snap, but with the wrong normal. In the end, the faces are not parallel to each other. Can you please help me? I've been wandering the internet for literally more than an hour.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Hello :). Blender is snapping with the "bottom" of the origin point. Adjust you origin point rotation before snapping and it will work.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer! Sadly, I don't know how to do what you're advising me to do. I found this (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-the-origin-without-rotating-the-geometry), but I can't "Paste Selection from Buffer", and even if I could, it would not solve my problem since I still can't rotate the object as I want.

Comment: Hey :). If you share your file (https://pasteall.org/blend/), I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you so much! Here is my file. As you will see, it thinks that it snapped perpendicularly because for some reason, it doesn't take the face's normal to be the object normal....
https://pasteall.org/blend/402735ad9bf24689ae3465fd9e529241

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender is snapping with the "negative Z axis" of the origin point.
Adjust you origin rotation and it will work.

1. Enable *Transform Only Origin* option and *Face snapping*
2. Snap the origin to a face - it'll inherit it's direction (Z+ axis)
3. Rotate the origin 180° along local Y axis (so it's Z-)

<sup>Snap origin and rotate it 180° along local Y axis</sup>
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank youuuuu! You are my saviour.. I don't know how I was supposed to find this on my own on the internet... For future readers, two things to remember here:
1- Transform can apply origin only
2- rotations can be relative to the local grid.

Final question: if I now want to set the origin back to the center of the face, should I do once more do "Edit>select face>set cursor to selection>Object mode>set origin to 3D cursor"? Or is there a faster way? Thanks once more <3

Comment: Hey :). Yes, in this case that's the way to do it.